# Plafond control on D365 FO, How can I check that the Plafond is less then the remaining amount in the intent letter?

Tags: event-handling, popup, x++, tax, dynamics-365-operations

I need to finish this task on D365 FO, i'm pretty new to it and I'm struggling trying to find examples and documentation online, so here I am, I hope someone can help me.
I need to implement the procedure for posting vendor invoices (both from purchase order and journal) by inserting a pop-up that is enabled when the amount to be deducted from the letter of intent relating to the document being posted is greater than the remaining amount of the letter. 
The pop-up should show the following message: 
"Amount to be deducted from the balance of the letter of intent greater than the remaining amount. Shall we continue?" 
The pop-up should have two buttons: 
Ok: If used, the system will have to account for the invoice despite the overhang. 
Cancel: If used, the system will cancel the posting.

I have tried with an Event Handler, checking if the remaining amount in the intent letters Table is less than 0 in order to at least display a message but of course it doesn't work.
The virtual machine I'm using is actually not working so I can't post my code unfortunately, but I will as soon as possible,even if it's useless I think. Does anyone have some hint on how can I do it? Thank you